# recursion with chartCodeAt to reduce string

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, for-loop, recursion

way to recursion to reduce string or array?
example case:

if we have. variable  `abcdfgh4zi` output must be `f4z`

BECAUSE after `d` it must be `e` and then after `h` it must  be `I`
it likes sorting...

I am trying it but failed using `charCodeAt`

```js
function reduce(data) {
  let result = ""
  if (data.length <= 1) {
    return result
  } else if (data.charCodeAt(data[0])+1  !==  data.charCodeAt(data[1])) {
    result += data[0]
  }
  return result + reduce(data.slice(1))

}

console.log(reduce('abcdfgh4zi')); // f4z
```

the result is the same like that data, and if I am using it `<`, it gonna be empty string

if data `"lmnop"` the result is true and it gonna return `empty string` because they are sorting

and here to find the next alphabet I found on SO If chartCodeAt doesn't work

```
var abc = (parseInt(data[0], 36) + 1) % 36;
 var nextAlphabet = ((!abc * 10 + abc).toString(36));
```

Comment: charCodeAt expects an index and you are giving it the character?

Comment: I just tried it with index and character , different chart code, ohh my bad , sorry :( , maybe we should using another ??

Answer (score 0):

`charCodeAt` expects an index, you are giving it the character. So you are doing `data.charCodeAt("a") + 1 !== data.charCodeAt("b")`

You are also storing the first character, so you would be storing "d" and not "f"

```js
function reduce(data) {
  let result = ""
  if (data.length <= 1) {
    return result
  } else if (data.charCodeAt(0)+1  !==  data.charCodeAt(1)) {
    result += data[1]
  }
  return result + reduce(data.slice(1))

}

console.log(reduce('abcdfgh4zi')); // f4z
```

Comment: ``console.log(reduce('abcdxefgh5wi')); // 'x5w'``
trying to use this, but the result not same like x5w

Comment: well that is different than what you posted before.... your logic would need to change to handle a few more cases. If you do `result += data[1];
        return result + reduce(data.slice(2))` it might work.

Comment: worked fine for me, I put that code in the else if and got the result